# Hi.I would like to filter and create new sheet for all the unique values present in specific column(G)

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to filter and create new sheet for all the unique values present in specific column(G).The only challenge which I am facing is some special character are there in that column (Ex:Database/ Administration).so the below code is showing error. New sheet name can be without special characters Kindly help me to fix this issue. Thanks!!

```
            Sub filter()
             Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          Dim x As Range
        Dim rng As Range
       Dim last As Long
       Dim sht As String

        'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
       sht = "Sheet1"

    'change filter column in the following code
   last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:l" & last)

         Sheets(sht).Range("G1:G"last).AdvancedFilterAction:=xlFilterCopy,         CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

     For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
        With rng
        .AutoFilter
     .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x.Value
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

       Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
       ActiveSheet.Paste
         End With
            Next x

       ' Turn off filter
       Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

       With Application
     .CutCopyMode = False
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      End With

      End Sub
```

Comment: What special characters are causing the issues? You can make an array to replace each of the special characters with either a space (not the best idea) or an underscore (do this one).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the special characters that are causing the issue are (\ , / , * , ? , : , [ , ]), Make an array with these characters and loop through the array to replace each character with an underscore.

```
Sub test()
Dim strTest As String
Dim strChars() As String
Dim strChar As String
Dim varTextChars As Variant

strChar = "\,/,*,?,:,[,]"
strChars() = Split(strChar, ",")

strTest = Range("E2").Value2
For Each varTextChars In strChars()
    strTest = Replace(strTest, varTextChars, "_")
    Range("G3").Value2 = strTest
Next varTextChars
End Sub
```

There are probably easier ways to make the array, but this works for the limited number of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions bellow will return a clean sheet name; size of 31 chars or less (max sheet name len)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CleanWsName(ByVal wsName As String) As String
    Const x = vbNullString

    wsName = Trim$(wsName)    'Trim, then remove [ ] / \ < > : * ? | "
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "[", x), "]", x), " ", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "/", x), "\", x), ":", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "<", x), ">", x), "*", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "?", x), "|", x), Chr(34), x)

    If Len(wsName) = 0 Then wsName = "DT " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss")
    CleanWsName = Left$(wsName, 31)         'Resize to max len of 31
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function CleanWsName2(ByVal wsName As String) As String
    Dim specialChars As Variant, i As Long

    specialChars = Split("[ ] / \ < > : * ? | " & Chr(34))

    wsName = Trim$(wsName)    'Trim, then remove [ ] / \ < > : * ? | "
    For i = 0 To UBound(specialChars)
        wsName = Replace(wsName, specialChars(i), vbNullString)
    Next
    wsName = Replace(wsName, " ", vbNullString)

    If Len(wsName) = 0 Then wsName = "DT " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss")
    CleanWsName2 = Left$(wsName, 31)     'Resize to max len of 31
End Function
```

---

Add the function to your module (under and outside your sub) and modify this line

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = CleanWsName(x.Value)
```

or to test it

```
wsName = CleanWsName2(" [ ] / \ < > : * ? | ""  ")
```